# Travel to UK with valid Visa & passport

Tags: visas, uk

What are the rules about when a passport with an entry clearance inside nears its expiration date? Are there any rules where my visa could be curtailed because my passport will expire soon?

Can i enter UK with a valid visa up to June 2016 and valid passport till October 2016, my travel period is for 5 days starting from first week of May 2016.

Comment: Which country issued the passport?

Answer (score 6):

At the time the person enters the UK, their passport must be valid for at least two months beyond the expiry of their entry clearance.

If not, the Immigration Officer is entitled to curtail the person's entry clearance so that the above condition will be valid.

In your case, your visa expires in June and your passport expires in October, that's four months and so you meet the requirements of this particular rule.

The rule itself is in [Paragraph 21](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk) of the Immigration Rules.

> The leave to enter or remain in the United Kingdom of the holder of a
>   passport or travel document whose permission to enter another country
>   has to be exercised before a given date may be restricted so as to
>   terminate at least 2 months before that date.

Answer (score 0):

When is the start of your UK visa validity? As I understood from your statement, your visa expires/ends in June and since you'll be travelling on May (before it expires), you'll be good to go!

If your travel date is within the validity of the visa, you can definitely travel to the UK!
Safe travel! :)

Comment: I think the real question here is whether the UK has a rule that requires passports to be valid for a particular period _after_ the trip -- for example the US requires six months after the planned departure as a general rule, except for a specific list of exceptions.

Comment: Yes, the questions squares on UK rule for passport to be valid for particular period after trip initiated, My passport will expire on 9th October  2016, i.e. valid for 6 months from date of traveling, traveling will be from 3rd may till 6th May.

Comment: I'm sorry! I didn't notice that, thanks for clearing it out :) You're passport is from what country? @AliHasanMalalla